# How to increase the timeout interval for long time communication to server

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have developed the ASP.net project with C#.i have execute the script on button click event. in this script i have accessed the information from the mysql server . if database contains lots of information then script required 2 to 5 min to execute this function.when i have accessed the data from server side to client side using button click it will disconnect the server connection & display the message as web page can not be display .
how to incresed the timeout interval for long time communication to server?

Answer (score 2):

You can increase execution timeout by setting executionTimeout attribute of httpRuntime element within web.config file under system.web element.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" ... />
```